# How to redirect multiple URL's on subdomain (feedburner mybrand->Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, rss, subdomain, feedburner

I use feedburner for my site but using my own URL/subdomain (using their [mybrand service](https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/79586)). So I have multiple feeds that look like:

- feeds.mysite.com/mainfeed
- feeds.mysite.com/podcastname

I want to stop using feedburner and take control of those feeds, but have no idea how to bring them back to my WordPress site as follows:

- feeds.mysite.com/mainfeed --> www.mysite.com/feed
- feeds.mysite.com/podcastname --> www.mysite.com/podcastnamefeed (I use blubrry powerpress for podcasts)

Is there a generic DNS redirect that can work? Or, is it a combo of DNS & 301 redirects? (Not even sure if the fact that it's feedburner even matters in this case.)

Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

Comment: .htaccess should be able to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Blubrry has specific instructions with images how to leave (migrate away from) FeedBurner. Here's the detailed link: 
http://create.blubrry.com/manual/syndicating-your-podcast-rss-feeds/leaving-feedburner/

You want to repeat the instructions on the page linked above for each feed. Before you delete each FeedBurner feed you want to double check that the feed FeedBurner was pulling is the feed you want FeedBurner to redirect to once you delete the feed. Also make sure you select the option "with permanent redirection".